# Pandas groupby date range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table where one of the columns is the date of occurrence (the dataframe is not indexed by date)

I want to group the table by date wherein all items which occurred prior to a certain date are grouped into one bucket. This would need to be cumulative, so later buckets will include all datapoints from earlier ones.

Here's the daterange object I need to group by:

```
date_rng = date_range('28/02/2010','31/08/2014',freq='3M')
```

Here's an example of a few datapoints in the table:

```
df_raw.head()
     Ticker   FY Periodicity  Measure     Val                Date
0  BP9DL90  2009         ANN     CPX  1000.00 2008-03-31 00:00:00
1  BP9DL90  2010         ANN     CPX   600.00 2009-03-25 00:00:00
2  BP9DL90  2010         ANN     CPX   600.00 2009-09-16 00:00:00
3  BP9DL90  2011         ANN     CPX   570.00 2010-03-17 00:00:00
4  BP9DL90  2011         ANN     GRM    57.09 2010-09-06 00:00:00

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't sound like 'grouping' (in the pandas sense) is the right approach here. That is a mutually exclusive operation. What are you actually trying to do? If you want to aggregate any of the columns, you may consider indexing by the date, and then e.g. `cumsum()`, or `pd.rolling_apply()` to get a 'running total'

Comment: I'm looking to filter data based on certain criteria. One of those criteria is "as of x date". Not looking to aggregate the data. I didn't know that pandas groupby was mutually exclusive - will probably have to set up loops to manually create subsets of the main table.

Comment: based on that, I would first try reading the data with date as index (see `index_col` and `parse_dates` args of `pd.read_csv()`), then you can loop easily like this : `for d in date_range: print(df_raw[:d])` which will print out the (sub)table up to date d.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a function that returns 1 if the date is in the date range you want, and then use this to group by:

```
# convert date column do datetime type
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'

def is_in_range(x):
   if x['Date'] > '28-02-2010 00:00:00' and x['Date'] < '31-08-2014 00:00:00':
       return 1
   else:
       return 0

data.groupby(df['date'].map(is_in_range))
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm actually looking to set up groups based on items with date less than each element in `date_rng`. So there would be one bucket per element in `date_rng`.

Comment: OK, i get it, I don't think you can have such cumulative groups in pandas groupby.